# Recreating collapsible force layout using d3 v4

Tags: force-layout, d3.js

I've been trying to create a Collapsible force layout using d3js v4, similar to this one: https://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/force-collapsible.html

I've been able to create the layout itself. But not able to update it. Can anyone help?

Here's my js code:

```js
var width = 960,
    height = 600;

var root = {
 "name": "server1900",
 "children": [{
  "name": "server913",
  "_children": null,
  "children": [{
   "name": "server948"
  }, {
   "name": "server946"
  }]
 }, {
  "name": "server912",
  "_children": null,
  "children": [{
   "name": "server984"
  }, {
   "name": "server983"
  }]
 }, {
  "name": "server911",
  "_children": null,
  "children": [{
   "name": "server999",
   "_children": null,
   "children": [{
    "name": "server992"
   }]
  }]
 }]
};

root = d3.hierarchy(root);

var i = 0;

var transform = d3.zoomIdentity;;

var nodeSvg, linkSvg, simulation, nodeEnter, linkEnter ;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .call(d3.zoom().scaleExtent([1 / 2, 8]).on("zoom", zoomed))
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(40,0)");

function zoomed() {
  svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}

simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
  .on("tick", ticked);

update();

function update() {
  var nodes = flatten(root);
  var links = root.links();

  simulation
    .nodes(nodes)

  simulation.force("link")
    .links(links);

  linkSvg = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; })

  linkSvg.exit().remove();

  linkSvg = linkSvg.enter()
      .append("line")
      .attr("class", "link");

  nodeSvg = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; })

  nodeSvg.exit().remove();

  nodeSvg = nodeSvg.enter()
    .append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .on("click", click)
      .call(d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended))

    nodeSvg.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 4  )
      .append("title")
        .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; })

    nodeSvg.append("text")
      .attr("dy", 3)
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children ? -8 : 8; })
      .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });



}

function ticked() {
  linkSvg
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  nodeSvg
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")"; });
}

function click(d) {
 if (d.children) {
  d._children = d.children;
  d.children = null;
    update();
    simulation.restart();
 } else {
  d.children = d._children;
  d._children = null;
    update();
    simulation.restart();
 }
}

function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart()
  simulation.fix(d);
}

function dragged(d) {
  simulation.fix(d, d3.event.x, d3.event.y);
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  simulation.unfix(d);
}

function flatten (root) {
  // hierarchical data to flat data for force layout
  var nodes = [];
  function recurse(node) {
    if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
    if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
    else ++i;
    nodes.push(node);
  }
  recurse(root);
  return nodes;
}
```

```css
line {
  stroke: #666;
}

.node {
  pointer-events: all;
}

circle {
  stroke: none;
  stroke-width: 40px;
}

.node text {
  font: 8px sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.0.0-alpha.50.min.js"></script>
```

Here's my fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/t4vzg650/4/

Thanks

Comment: What kind of update do you mean? Are there any errors or is it just not showing the desired behavior?

Comment: @altocumulus After clicking on a node, if the node has children, children will expand/collapse, i.e., map will update to show/hide new nodes. I'm referring that has update. No errors. Not showing the desired behavior.

Comment: Are you sure this d3.version.alpha has not errors?

Comment: @Klaujesi I'm not sure. But, d3 v4 is about to be released. Hoping that it will be stable enough. And, my graph done with d3 v3 with large data set has performance problems. So, trying to do that using v4 hoping that performance may improve. The thing is, d3 v4 has some major changes. I think I'm missing out something.

Comment: I forgot to call simulation.restart(). Now adding and removing nodes seems to be working but nodes and link positions are off. Updated the fiddle.

Comment: May be I'm not adding and removing children properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I forgot to merge old nodes after enter().

```
link = svg.selectAll(".link").data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; })
var linkEnter = link.enter().append("line").attr("class", "link");
link = linkEnter.merge(link);
```

Thanks to Mike Bostock for helping me with this problem. I thought there was an issue with d3 v4, turns out I didn't read changes fully :|

Refer this for more info: https://github.com/d3/d3-force/issues/37

Fixed fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t4vzg650/6/

Comment: Great help. For anyone else plodding through this, it may also be useful to be sure to use the key function (https://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/#key-functions) that the @kirupakaranh has (correctly) used: `function(d) { return d.id; }`. Lots of moving parts, and the key function in addition to the merge solved my issue.