# d3 v4 update/merge grouped data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to update data for a force simulation in D3 v4, similar to [this unsuccessful attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38623530/d3-v4-update-force-layout) and semi-similar to [this successful one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38011393/recreating-collapsible-force-layout-using-d3-v4). CodePen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pbQAbW?editors=1010)

Instead of joining the new nodes it appears to be doubling all the nodes (see pictures). It does not seem to be refreshing the graph correctly either.

[image: initial graph]
(initial graph)

[image: graph after adding data]
(after adding data)

HTML:

```
<button onclick="addData()">Add Data</button>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
```

JavaScript:

```
function addData() {
    graph.nodes.push({"id": "Extra1", "group": 11},{"id": "Extra2", "group": 11})
    graph.links.push({"source": "Extra1", "target": "Valjean", "strength": 1},{"source": "Extra1", "target": "Extra2", "strength": 2})
    update()
    simulation.restart()
}

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var link, linkEnter, nodeWrapper, nodeWrapperEnter;

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
    .on("tick", ticked);

var allLinkG = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "allLinkG")

var allNodeG = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "allNodeG")

update()
simulation.restart()

function update(){

  link = allLinkG
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links, function(d){ return d.id }) 

  link.exit().remove()

  linkEnter = link
    .enter().append("line");

  link = linkEnter.merge(link).attr("class","merged");


  nodeWrapper = allNodeG
    .selectAll("nodeWrapper")
    .data(graph.nodes, function(d) { return d.id; })

  nodeWrapper.exit().remove();

  nodeWrapperEnter = nodeWrapper.enter()
    .append("g").attr("class","nodeWrapper")
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 2.5)

  nodeWrapper = nodeWrapperEnter
    .merge(nodeWrapper).attr("class","merged");


  simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes);

  simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);
}

function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    nodeWrapper
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
}
```

Thanks very much for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few issues here:

1. Your `selectAll` is selecting by element type `nodeWrapper`, you meant by class `.nodeWrapper`.
2. You change the class name to "merged" after your `.merge`, you can't do this as it breaks future selections by `.nodeWrapper` class.
3. When you `.merge` your selection, you are merging `circle`s with `g`s. You should stay consistent and operate on the `g`s only.

Quick refactor:

```
function update() {

  link = allLinkG
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links, function(d) {
      return d.id
    })

  link.exit().remove()

  linkEnter = link
    .enter().append("line");

  link = linkEnter.merge(link).attr("class", "merged");

  nodeWrapper = allNodeG
    .selectAll(".nodeWrapper") //<-- class nodeWrapper
    .data(graph.nodes, function(d) {
      return d.id;
    })

  nodeWrapperEnter = nodeWrapper.enter()
    .append("g").attr("class", "nodeWrapper"); //<-- enter selection should be gs

  nodeWrapperEnter //<-- append  your circles
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 2.5)

  nodeWrapper = nodeWrapperEnter //<-- merge, don't change class
    .merge(nodeWrapper);

  nodeWrapper.exit().remove();  //<-- and the exit

  simulation
    .nodes(graph.nodes);

  simulation.force("link")
    .links(graph.links);
}
```

**Note**, I also modified your `tick` function to operate on the `g` instead of the `circle`:

```
nodeWrapper
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  });
```

---

Full code is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZnMwL4933vKjLT5MBkZP?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. I was assuming `.attr("class","merged")` would append a class instead of replacing it. `.classed("merged",true)` is what I should have used instead.